# Seaborn change x axis values

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

I am trying to do a dotted bar plot (like the one I created below) but change the x axis labels to be the names of the categories (a and b) instead of the numbers 0-1. I like the idea of being able to see the distribution at a glance (orange vs blue dots).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'ballot': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
     'whichballot':[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]}
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(d)

dfwl['whichballot'] = dfwl['whichballot'].astype('category')
dfwl['ballot'] = dfwl['ballot'].astype('category').cat.codes
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(dfwl.reset_index())

fig=sns.pairplot(x_vars=pd.Categorical(['ballot']), y_vars=['vote'], data=dfwl, hue="whichballot", size=5)

plt.show(fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal scatter plot seems to be enough to produce the desired plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'ballot': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
     'whichballot':[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

plt.scatter(df.ballot, df.vote, c=df.whichballot)
plt.margins(x=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if using seaborn, a `stripplot` would make sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'ballot': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
     'whichballot':[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

ax = sns.stripplot(x='ballot', y='vote', data=df, jitter=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, in order to see the distribution, one would probably rather use a boxplot or violinplot.